# Unable to resolve service of ASP.NET sample project (using core 1 instead of 2)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm using ASP.Net core 1 instead of 2 and try to get the sample of OpenIdDict running on my system. I did some little changes to make the project buildable for me. But I get en error while debugging and have no idea how to handle it. Does anybody has an idea / hint for me? Thanks a lot!

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration' while attempting
>   to activate 'AuthorizationServer.Startup'.    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider
>   provider)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.StartupLoader.LoadMethods(IServiceProvider
>   services, Type startupType, String environmentName)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__1(IServiceProvider
>   sp)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ScopedCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider
>   provider)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider
>   provider, Type serviceType)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider
>   provider)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureStartup()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()

EDIT: add program code

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AuthorizationServer.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using OpenIddict.Abstractions;
using OpenIddict.Core;
using OpenIddict.EntityFrameworkCore.Models;
using System.Net.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;

namespace AuthorizationServer
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();

            var connection = @"...";
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(connection);

                options.UseOpenIddict();
            });

            services.AddOpenIddict()

                .AddCore(options =>
                {
                    options.UseEntityFrameworkCore()
                           .UseDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();
                })

                .AddServer(options =>
                {
                    options.UseMvc();

                    options.EnableTokenEndpoint("/connect/token");

                    options.AllowClientCredentialsFlow();

                    options.DisableHttpsRequirement();
                })

                .AddValidation();

            services.AddSingleton(Configuration); //changed here
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

            app.UseOAuthValidation();
            //app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();

            app.UseWelcomePage();

            InitializeAsync(app.ApplicationServices).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        private async Task InitializeAsync(IServiceProvider services)
        {
            using (var scope = services.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
            {
                var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
                await context.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();

                var manager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<OpenIddictApplicationManager<OpenIddictApplication>>();

                if (await manager.FindByClientIdAsync("console") == null)
                {
                    var descriptor = new OpenIddictApplicationDescriptor
                    {
                        ClientId = "console",
                        ClientSecret = "388D45FA-B36B-4988-BA59-B187D329C207",
                        DisplayName = "My client application",
                        Permissions =
                        {
                            OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Endpoints.Token,
                            OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.GrantTypes.ClientCredentials
                        }
                    };

                    await manager.CreateAsync(descriptor);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace AuthorizationServer
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .AddCommandLine(args)
                .Build();

            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .ConfigureLogging(options => options.AddConsole())
                .ConfigureLogging(options => options.AddDebug())
                .UseConfiguration(configuration)
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible in ASP.NET Core 1.x to inject `IConfiguration` into your `Startup` constructor. Instead, you can inject a `IHostingEnvironment` and build your own `IConfiguration` instance, like so:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();
}
```

You can exclude the `AddJsonFile` lines if you don't have any `appsettings.json` files - What I've included is just an example based on the generated templates from ASP.NET Core 1.x.

Comment: iirc the `Configuration` property in 1.x templates if of type `IConfigurationRoot`, not `IConfiguration`. Injection should work, if registered properly. But I wouldn't advise it (leaks infrastructure into your services, better use `IOption<T>`

Comment: @Tseng I think that's right too - `IConfigurationRoot`. The OP was already using `IConfiguration` so I went with that to keep things simple without losing anything. I agree with the `IOptions<T>` stuff too - it's generally great advice but given that the OP is just trying to build an existing sample, it's perhaps out of context here (imo). Thanks for the input.

Comment: `IConfigurationRoot` inherits from `IConfiguration` so it can be used as drop in replacement, but the registration has to be `services.AddSingleton<IConfigurationRoot>(Configuration);` not `services.AddSingleton(Configuration);` (as in your deleted answer) because the later one creates a registration for `IConfigurationRoot`, but none for `IConfiguration`. If you want both you need to register **both**, `IConfigurationRoot` and `IConfiguration` **explicitly**

Comment: @Tseng I deleted the other answer because we don't need *either* of `IConfiguration` or `IConfigurationRoot` in DI in order to resolve the problem at hand. I mistakenly thought the error was post-`Startup` but it was actually the `Startup` constructor itself that was causing the error.